# Communication between Two Processes using Named Pipes and Semaphores

Tags: c, mutex, pipe, semaphore

I'm trying to communicate between two processes (like a chat room). Each process has its own terminal window opened. I'm using named pipes for communication.

Here's what I did:

I have a FIFO_FILE named "MYFILE". Process A writes a new line to MYFILE and process B reads from MYFILE and outputs the line to process B's terminal display. However, if process B wants to write a new line to MYFILE, (from what I understand about semaphore) process A will be blocked from reading/writing to MYFILE until process B finishes writing.

**What I want to achieve is:** When two processes want to write, no process should be blocked when other process is ahead of it writing to the file.

The only way I can think of is to have two FIFO_FILEs. But How to achieve this implementation?
Or is there other way to achieve?

I was told to use Consumer-Producer pattern but I don't see how this will solve my problem.

Any help would be great. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion - you really don't need semaphores with named pipes, do you?

Just write whenever you want, and, under most circumstances, you'll block until there's something to read.

Here are a couple of short tutorial for using named pipes with shell scripts on Linux:

- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156?page=0,1
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash

Comment: not really. But I thought using semaphores to prevent another process writing/reading.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some kind of *nix environment this won't work.  Pipe read/writes are guaranteed to be atomic so long as they are under PIPE_BUF length.  Having both processes write to the same fifo at the same time doesn't really make sense.  Think of it like writing to a file - why would you want the content of two independent writes to be interspersed?  How would you make sense of it?

You really should look into using multiple fifos.  Even then you will either need to use multi-threading or non-blocking FIFOs and `select` or `poll` to achieve what I think you are really aiming to accomplish.

Comment: I was thinking as two-way chat program, because no one is blocked while typing messages, not like one outputs something and waits for reply from another process. But I will definitely look up into "multiple FIFOs" --- never thought of this term but thanks!

Comment: I think we may be talking past each other.  The problem with one FIFO is that both processes would have to open it as read/write.  I suspect you are thinking that the reader will necessarily receive what the writer wrote.  That is not the case with FIFOs.  Depending on the timing it is entire possible process A can write to the FIFO and then immediately read what it just wrote.  Process B will never see it.  With 2 FIFOs one process reads 1 FIFO and the other writes to it.  And the reverse with the 2nd FIFO.  Or simplify your life and use unix domain sockets which are better suited for this.